# TypeScript strict null check on field of object in array

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, despite checking for null on a nullable field in an object array  (with `strictNullCheck` set to `true`), the compiler still complains that the 'Object is possibly undefined'. Consider the following:

```
interface IA {
    d?: Date
}
const arr : IA[] = [{d: new Date()}];

console.error(arr[0].d == null ? "" : arr[0].d.toString());  
                                           // ^ complains that "Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

[Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20d%3F%3A%20Date%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3A%20IA%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7Bd%3A%20new%20Date()%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.error(arr%5B0%5D.d%20%3D%3D%20null%20%3F%20%22%22%20%3A%20arr%5B0%5D.d.toString())%3B) to TS PlayGround (set `strictNullCheck` on)

However, if we have:

```
const a : IA = {d: new Date()};
console.error(a.d == null ? "" : a.d.toString());
```

then the compiler is happy.

Why is this the desired behavior? And what would be the correct practice here if I don't want to turn `strictNullCheck` off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't track array elements by their index; in other words there's no mechanism in the type system that identifies that two expressions `arr[0]` are necessarily pointing to the same object.

In general this is a good assumption because the ordering of array elements is *not* guaranteed to remain the same between any two observations of the same element. We can tell from inspection that e.g. you didn't call `sort` between those two accesses, but in any other case where two expressions aren't evaluated right after the other, it's not known for sure that `arr[0]` points to the same object both times.

Comment: Thanks, but here the expressions *are* evaluated one after the other, so I'm just missing the point on why this is different from a `var` (which can also be mutated by a nested function or such)

Comment: *You* know that, but TypeScript has not implemented a special case to identify that situation

Comment: OK, don't complete understand still, but maybe that's not the objective.. what is the recommended practice here then (if I don't want to suppress `strictNullCheck`)?

Comment: Extract it to a `const` or use the postfix `!` operator (`arr[0].d!.toString()`)

Comment: It's easier to understand if your mental model of how TS work is "A set of heuristics and tracking rules identify when two expressions resolve to the same object" instead of "TS starts with a perfect model of the universe and discards data on purpose"